# How to set onclick listener for tabView with listed items and move to a new Activity

Tags: android

Here I created a simple Tablayout with some options under it. When clicked on particular item the application should open another activity containing the particular class. Could Some one please help how to write the code for item onclick listener .Here I am attaching the code of my TabLayout java class and my versionModel java class with xml included. I am also attaching the screenshot of the app. So as in the screenshot when i click on the Topwear , page containing Topwear should open.[image: Screenshot]

TabAnimationActivity.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.suleiman.material.R;
import com.suleiman.material.adapter.SimpleRecyclerAdapter;
import com.suleiman.material.model.VersionModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TabAnimationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SimpleRecyclerAdapter adapter;
Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_animation);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabanim_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    showToast("One");
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        showToast("Two");

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        showToast("Three");

                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new    ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new   DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_material_light)), "Men");
    adapter.addFrag(new    DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.ripple_material_light)), "Women");
    adapter.addFrag(new     DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_material_dark)), "Kids");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tab_switch, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_switch:
                Intent intent = new Intent(TabAnimationActivity.this,    TabsHeaderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    public static class DummyFragment extends Fragment {
        int color;
        SimpleRecyclerAdapter adapter;

        public DummyFragment() {
        }

        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public DummyFragment(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, container, false);

            final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)     view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_bg);
            frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)     view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_scrollableview);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new     LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < VersionModel.data.length; i++) {
                list.add(VersionModel.data[i]);
            }

            adapter = new SimpleRecyclerAdapter(list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

VersionModel.java

```
public class VersionModel {
public String name;

public static final String[] data = {"Topwear", "Bottomwear", "Footwear",
        "Sports wear", "Innerwear &Sleepwear", "SmartWearables",
        "Watches", "Accessories", "PersonalGrooming", "T-Shirts"};

    VersionModel(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

dummy_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dummyfrag_bg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_material_light">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dummyfrag_scrollableview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope This may give you an idea on Recyclerview OnItemClick.

```
      RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_scrollableview);
                    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); // to improve performance
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new YourRecylerAdapter());        
                    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener( new RecyclerClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 

YourDetailedActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }}));  
return v;
```

Comment: Do I need to add the fallowing code inside the appCompact activity or inside the public onCreateView method.

Comment: inside OncreateView of DummyFragment

Comment: And what is this RecyclerClickListener.It was not recognised by the complier.

Comment: Cannot resolve the symbol RecyclerClickListener. This is what it is saying. Please help in this because I am stuck here from more than 3days.